# google sheet conditional formatting of same row

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements

In the conditional formatting, how to make the first column of data meet the date conditions, the same row of data will show the background color.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "Apply to range", you specify the entire range of cells you want to potentially be highlighted. Then, use a custom formula that refers to the exact cell in the first row of the range that you want to deal with, and google sheets will infer the rest of the rows. In your example, set range equal to `A2:D20`, and the custom formula to `=$A2<TODAY()`.

Comment: Thank you for  your very detailed reply.

Comment: Happy to help! If it solved your problem, please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark :)

Comment: Hi, I am studing google sheet ,do you have any idea about my new question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963336/date-of-cell-validation-in-google-sheet