# Date of cell validation in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

May I ask
How to deal with that the date of the cell below must be no earlier than the cell above in the entire column?
Can the ArrayFormula function deal with the problem?

Comment: I found it could use the date condition in data validation with offset function.

Answer (score 1):

use custom formula in data validation:

```
=A2>A1
```

[image]

Comment: I use the Criteria/date/on or after/=A2>offset(A2,-1,0) and it work.